# Available controls to perform filtering on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I need to apply filtering on my gridview columns. For that i need to keep a dropdown that would contain the text of that column. For e.g. Emp ID column contains data as Emp1,Emp2,Emp3.. hence the filter would also contain the same data.

The filter needs to be kept in the gridview header and selecting the apt data, say Emp1 would bind the grid again and filter the grid with selected data.

My Question: Other that aspx dropdownlist and ajax combobox, which are FREE options available that could be use to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: The filtering that i am concerned with is wrt UI and not filtering in the code..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll be using the same datasource for the dropdowns, you can specify the DataTextField and DataValueField in markup, and bind the dropdowns to the datasource in the RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset isn't that large (ie, you're not using paging), the simplest option would probably be to use [DataTables](http://datatables.net/).  Here's an example on [filtering](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)